# How can I add the template(layout) page functionality to Haskell Servant website?

Tags: html, haskell, layout, servant

I'm looking for simple and easy way to add template or layouts functionality to a web site in servant. So when I have a few similar pages, I don't have to create a layout for each of them completely from scratch, I can create a master or layout page and then each page can inherit it and change the html layout appropriately for itself. Everyone is familiar with that.

How can I do that?
Currently I have using below code,

```
type API = 
  "items" :> Get '[JSON] [MyData] :<|>
  Raw

app :: Application
app = serve api server

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

server :: Server API
server = 
  getItems :<|> 
  serveDirectory "my_html"

startApp :: IO ()
startApp = run 3333 app
```

Note that I'd not like to use an approach where you have to desribe the html layout in Haskell code.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I want to read a template from an html file, not to create it staticaly in Haskell.

Comment: Ah. Well, I reckon it would become a heck lot _simpler_ if you defined it in Haskell (then you could just make the master layout _parametric_ on anything you wish to customise), but it should also be possible with an externally-read html file.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, in haskell an html layout? what if it's complex? and re-compile each time I change it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, " but it should also be possible with an externally-read html file." -- how to do that?

Comment: Well, IMO, the more complex something is, the more reason to do it in Haskell! Recompiling after a change is also quite a good idea, because it immediately catches most errors you might make. — That said, I acknowledge you may have good reasons to stick with plain html; as I said it _should_ be possible, but you'll need to parse the html and put it back. There are probably some nice ways to do this with lenses, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like [shakespeare](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shakespeare) which allows you to write HTML in actual HTML syntax inside a Haskell source file (or parse it from a file). It's designed for yesod but there is no actual dependency on yesod so you can plug it into any web framework. It looks like [there is](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-ede-0.5.1) something similar for servant but it isn't maintained nor have I ever used it.

Comment: Have you seen [servant-ede](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-ede)? It shows one way you can do templating with servant. I'm sure other approaches exist.